# How does something like mailspring or newton give read receipts?

Tags: email

I have no idea the technology behind how mailspring or newton is able to show a read receipt for email and link included in the email.

Does the link click first go through their email before the recipient gets there?

I have the rough idea of how the email's images might first go through their server so they know the image has been loaded, but what about an email that is text only?

I am really only interested in the basic idea, not here to copy their business features.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know if I understand problem - but mail may have URL to small white image (with size of one pixel) so mail loads image but you don't see it. And it has to be URL to image on external server - and this server see when your mail downloads image. And if this url has some unique value then it know which mail was readed. It is/was popular method on webpages to get any statistic when user don't run JavaScript (and it can't run i.e. Google Analytics)

Comment: as I remeber mail could send (probably in headers) request for sending back `read receipt` and in some clients you can see option to turn it off (not send requests, and not send back confirmation)   ie. [How to Request a Return Receipt for Your Emails with Thunderbird - CCM](https://ccm.net/faq/11069-thunderbird-request-a-return-receipt-for-your-emails)